# Elegant way of dynamically adding columns that are functions of previous columns

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a better way to achieve the result below?
I'm commonly using this sort of coding approach for operating on many columns (imagine `v2` had 20 + columns, so I need a dynamic way to build new columns)

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(m = 1:10, v1 = rnorm(10, 1), v2 = rnorm(10, 1), v3 = rnorm(10, 1))

run_across <- function(x, y = "m", z = c("v1")) {
#  browser()
x[,c(paste0(y, ".", z), paste0(y, ".div.", z)) := list(get(y) * get(z), get(y) / get(z))]
}

# works fine for an individual case:
run_across(dt)

# Error: param z returns the values of column v1:
dt[, lapply(X=.SD, FUN = run_across, x = dt, y = "m"), .SDcols = paste0("v", 1:3)]

# This has desired result, but is there a more elegant approach?
invisible(lapply(paste0("v", 1:3), run_across, x = dt, y = "m"))
```

Comment: from my point of view it's a matter of data structure - once you convert to long format, your problem is gone - e.g. `dt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "m"); run_across(dt, y = "m", z = "value")`

Comment: Great point.  You should make this an answer.  How do I get back to the original format though with `dcast` after doing the multiplication?  v2 <- run_across(v, "m", "value"); dcast(v2, formula= m ~variable) isn't what I expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "elegance" is a very subjective term that is not really helpful in evaluating code, from my point of view.

Second, the approach the OP offered themself is not bad at all, using a sinlge `lapply`-call.

Third, the best I can think of to making this a more "elegant" (in the sense of R-like or simple) operation, is to convert your data to long format before running your custom function:

```
dt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "m")
run_across(dt, y = "m", z = "value")
```

That means, you can do it in a single call to `run_across` without looping.

If you need to convert to wide-format afterwards, you can use `dcast`:

```
dcast(dt, m ~ variable, value.var = c("value","m.value", "m.div.value"))
```